# RTK Query where result is not JSON parsable

Tags: react-native, rtk-query

I am doing this as a learning exercise for react-toolkit:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const getIPv4AddressApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "getIPv4Address",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://ip4.8n1.org/",
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getIPv4Address: builder.query<string, void>({
      query: () => "",
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetIPv4AddressQuery } = getIPv4AddressApi;
```

When run, I get an error

```
{"status":"PARSING_ERROR","originalStatus":200,"data":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n","error":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 6"}
```

How can I just return the whole response without it trying to JSON parse? Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

See [parsing a response](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response)

```js
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getIPv4Address: builder.query<string, void>({
      query: () => "",
      responseHandler: "text"
    }),
  }),
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide your own ResponseHandler in order for the response body to not be parsed as JSON. From https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response

```
Parsing a Response

By default, fetchBaseQuery assumes that every Response you get will be parsed as json. In the event that you don't want that to happen, you can customize the behavior by specifying an alternative response handler like text, or take complete control and use a custom function that accepts the raw Response object — allowing you to use any Response method.

The responseHandler field can be either:

    TypeScript
    JavaScript

type ResponseHandler =
  | 'content-type'
  | 'json'
  | 'text'
  | ((response: Response) => Promise<any>)

The "json" and "text" values instruct fetchBaseQuery to the corresponding fetch response methods for reading the body. content-type will check the header field to first determine if this appears to be JSON, and then use one of those two methods. The callback allows you to process the body yourself.
```

More helpful discussions here as well: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2440

Examples from the GitHub:

```
export const api = generatedAuthApi.enhanceEndpoints({
  endpoints: {
    users: {
      query: queryArg => ({
        url: '/users',
        method: 'POST',
        body: queryArg.body,
        responseHandler: (response: { text: () => any }) => response.text()
      })
    },
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving the query: as an empty string, you can specified the data format. Here is an example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaNr4.png)

Comment: Please add example code as the link may be removed.